# background image doesn't shrink as screen size in firefox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, shrink

I have a div called `.outer` which contained a div called `.film`, and the div `.film` has some of image divs.

The problem is `.outer` div doesn't shrink it as the screen size in Firefox like this picture:

[image]

As you can see, the div is shrinking well in Chrome(left side) but not in Firefox(right side).

Are there any ways to shrink the `.outer` div in Firefox just like Chrome does?

This is the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section, div {
  position: relative;
}
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.film {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 .8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 33.3333%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/3p6TLYE.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.film:nth-child(2n-1) {
  opacity: .4;
  transform: scale();
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="film"></div>
      <div class="film"></div>
      <div class="film"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in behavior in firefox, I did "reload frame" after setting 247x381 and got the same behavior in firefox too...

Answer (score 0):

First thing which comes to mind is, setting `display`, `width` and `height` property of `html` and `body` tag.

Have you tried the following?

```css
html, body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution I can find is that changing your 500px to auto that works in firefox I have tested while now the maximum width is changed which can be controlled by max-width tag just change your outer with my code :

```
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution and add the answer for the people who are having the same problem like me.

In Firefox, you should not use the `px` units if you want to shrink your div as the screen size. Use the `padding-bottom` instead of a height of the image like this:

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%; // basic size of the holder(outer). Use percentage unit to control it.
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.film {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 .8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70.3333%; // Set the height of the images.
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/3p6TLYE.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.film:nth-child(2n-1) {
  opacity: .4;
  transform: scale();
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="film"></div>
    <div class="film"></div>
    <div class="film"></div>
</div>
```